# Android - retrieve image and video in a ascendant temporal order

Tags: android, provider

Would it be possible to retrieve all the images and video of the providers MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns and MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns in a temporally ascendant order ?

To explain more precisely, I need a list of all the videos and images containing for each tuple the following attribute : id, date, name, latitude, longitude, path, mimeType, data.

But these information are divided in three tables, one for each kind of media : MediaStore.MediaColumns, Images.ImageColumns and MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.

Is it possible with one query ?

I think that a solution is to query the id in MediaStore.MediaColumns table (in a temporally ascendant order) and then, for each id obtained, to do one query in a specific table, depending of the mimetype : in MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns if it is an image or in MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns if it is a video...

The temporally ascendant order is important for me. The solution to query first the image and then the video would not be convenient...I do not want to classify both list results...

Thanks a lot if you can help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would suggest you to use a UNION operation like in the following example:

```
select  _id, date_modified, _display_name, latitude, longitude, _data, mime_type from video UNION ALL select  _id, date_modified, _display_name, latitude, longitude, _data, mime_type from images ORDER BY date_modified ASC;
```

This query returns a list of all videos and images from both tables, and the result is sorted by date_modified. However, android's ContentResolver's query API is not exactly designed for full-scale SQL requests. Hence, I am not sure how to fit this compound request into the content resolver's query function.

So, I think you should exec separate query for Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI sorted as you wish and then collate the results.

Comment: when you say "android's ContentResolver's query API is not exactly designed for full-scale SQL requests", you mean that it won't work? not recommended? be slower than the other solution?

Comment: @shem What I meant to say is that you simply can't make a "real"/raw SQL query to ContentResolver via its "query" method. It mimics the SQL style to some extent by the signature of the method. However, try to make that compound request I gave in my answer. How would you put two "select" blocks from two different tables in one call to "ContentResolver.query()"? that is what I am talking about.